# where() not working in codeigniter database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote this code for search in my table search for a string in posts where `show = 1`.
but when i run this code `where('show',1)` not affected and rows where having `show = 0` returned from database, what this problem?

```
    public function json_search($str)
    {
        $out['Threadt'] = $this->db
        ->select('id')
        ->from('posts')
        ->like('title',$str)
        ->or_like('story',$str)
        ->or_like('description',$str)
        ->or_like('full-story',$str)
        ->where('date <',time())
        ->where('show',1)
        ->get()
    ->result_array();
     }
```

Comment: Try show, '1' (wrapped in quotes)

Comment: I Try `'1'` but not worked :(

Comment: At first glance, everything looks ok to me. If you run $this->db->last_query() does the query look OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this, this should work:

```
function json_search($str)
{
    $where  = "( story like '%".$str."%' OR title like '%".$str."%' OR description like '%".$str."%' OR full-story like '%".$str."%' )";
    $out['Threadt'] = $this->db
    ->select('id')
    ->from('posts')
    /*->like('title',$str)
    ->or_like('story',$str)
    ->or_like('description',$str)
    ->or_like('full-story',$str)*/
    ->where( $where, false, false )
    ->where('date <',time())
    ->where('show',1)
    ->get()
    ->result_array();
 }
```

See the commented part above, when you're using it like this, you are appending `OR` clauses and this interferes with the `show` clause.